# Google oauth gives 500 Internal Server Error if entered wrong token

Tags: oauth, token, internal-server-error

Here is my code

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("name");
$client->setClientId('id');
$client->setClientSecret('secret');
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email");
$token_data = $client->verifyIdToken($token);
```

verifyIdToken is triggering 500 Internal Server Error if token is invalid. Can you help me to figure out how to get rid of that? And how can i verify the token is valid or not?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.

I had to use try-catch to catch exceptions. If token is invalid, it will trigger an exception.